# drag and drop rasterImageviewer in winform applications (c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, leadtools-sdk

I want to develop a simple windows form to display images. I want to use leadtools for that.

I added RasterImageList, RasterImageViewer, RasterPictureBox and RasterThumbnailBrowser to the toolbox of visual studio.

I tried to drag and drop rasterImageViewer inside the form but it didn't work. It simply displays a small icon of leadtools at the bottom of the form (outside of it).

[leadtools http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/163652leadtools.jpg](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/163652leadtools.jpg)

I did setup the environment with a licence key, I added the needed "dll" files in "references", etc.

I am able to change the location of the rasterImageViewer and its size in the property tab but it does not display anything.

Answer (score 0):

Idrees,
In some versions of LEADTOOLS, you’ll need to reference these DLLs in the project to be able to add the RasterImageViewer control:

- Leadtools.dll
- Leadtools.Codecs.dll
- Leadtools.Drawing.dll
- Leadtools.WinForms.dll
- Leadtools.WinForms.Design.dll

If you’re still facing problems, please specify the version of LEADTOOLS you’re using, either here or in an email to LEAD support.